# Add String Item In a List in SharedPreferences: Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, sharedpreferences

So I have this product page where I would want to show recent visited product a.k.a product history. So I save this product id every time a user visits the page in the `initState`, the problem is where am supposed to show the the history is in another page and it keeps showing one item(recent visited) instead of a list of them all(It replaces the previous one). Here's my code

```
...
class _ProductInfoScreenState extends State<ProductInfoScreen> {
//initialise the list
 List<String> visitedProduct =  [];

 Future setViewedProduct()async{
    visitedProduct.add(widget.productId);
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    prefs.setStringList('viewedProductHistory', visitedProduct);
  }
@override
  void initState() {
    getImage();
    //Here
     setViewedProduct();
    super.initState();
  }

}

....

///Getting the saved list

 class _SearchTabState extends State<SearchTab> {
...
  Future getVisitedProductsFuture()async{
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var visitedProductsList = prefs.getStringList('viewedProductHistory');
    return visitedProductsList;
  }

...
SizedBox(
                      height: 200,
                      width: size.width,
                      child: FutureBuilder(
                          future: getVisitedProductsFuture(),
                          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot recentVisitedProductsSnapshot) {
                            if(recentVisitedProductsSnapshot.hasData){
                              return SizedBox(
                                height: 130.0,
                                width:size.width,
                                child: ListView(
                                  shrinkWrap: true,
                                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                  children: List.generate(recentVisitedProductsSnapshot.data.length, (index) {
                                    return Padding(
                                      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 14.0),
                                      child: FutureBuilder(
                                        future: ShopService().getSingleShopProduct(recentVisitedProductsSnapshot.data[index]),
                                        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot actualVisitedProductSnapshot) {
                                         if(actualVisitedProductSnapshot.hasData){
                                           print(recentVisitedProductsSnapshot.data.length);
                                           return InkWell(
                                             onTap: (){

                                             },
                                             child: Column(
                                               crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                               children: [
                                                 Stack(
                                                   children: [
                                                     Container(
                                                       height: 130.0,
                                                       width: 130.0,
                                                       decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                           borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                                                           image: DecorationImage(
                                                               image: NetworkImage(actualVisitedProductSnapshot.data['product']['featured_image']['digital_ocean_url'].toString(),),
                                                               fit: BoxFit.contain
                                                           )
                                                       ),
                                                     ),
                                                     Positioned(
                                                       top: 5.0,
                                                       right: 5.0,
                                                       child: FutureBuilder(
                                                           future: ShopService().getWishlist(widget.user.id.toString()),
                                                           builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot wishlistSnapshot) {
                                                             var containsItem;
                                                             if(wishlistSnapshot.hasData){
                                                               containsItem = wishlistSnapshot.data.firstWhere((e)=> e['product_id'].toString() ==
                                                                   actualVisitedProductSnapshot.data['product_id'].toString(), orElse:() => {});
                                                               if(containsItem['product_id'].toString() == actualVisitedProductSnapshot.data['product_id'].toString()){
                                                                 return InkWell(
                                                                   onTap: (){
                                                                     ShopService().removeFromWishlist(
                                                                         containsItem['id'].toString()
                                                                     ).then((value) {
                                                                       if(value['error'] ){
                                                                         setState(() {

                                                                         });
                                                                         Flushbar(
                                                                           margin: const EdgeInsets.only( bottom: 12.0, left: 12.0, right: 12.0),
                                                                           borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                                                           message: 'Please try again later!!',
                                                                           duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
                                                                         ).show(context);
                                                                       }
                                                                       else{
                                                                         setState(() {

                                                                         });
                                                                         Flushbar(
                                                                           margin: const EdgeInsets.only( bottom: 12.0, left: 12.0, right: 12.0),
                                                                           borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                                                           message: 'Removed from wishlist!',
                                                                           duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
                                                                         ).show(context);

                                                                       }

                                                                     });
                                                                   },
                                                                   child: Container(
                                                                     height: 35.0,
                                                                     width: 35.0,
                                                                     decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                                       borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14.0),
                                                                       color: AppColors.fontHeaderColor.withOpacity(0.2),
                                                                     ),
                                                                     child: const Center(
                                                                       child: Icon( Icons.favorite_rounded, color: Colors.redAccent,),
                                                                     ),
                                                                   ),
                                                                 );
                                                               }else{
                                                                 return InkWell(
                                                                   onTap: (){
                                                                     ShopService().addToWishlist(
                                                                       actualVisitedProductSnapshot.data['merchant_id'].toString(),
                                                                       widget.user.id.toString(),
                                                                       actualVisitedProductSnapshot.data['product_id'].toString(),
                                                                       actualVisitedProductSnapshot.data['id'].toString(),
                                                                     ).then((value) {
                                                                       setState(() {

                                                                       });
                                                                       if(value['error'] && value['data'].isNotEmpty){
                                                                         Flushbar(
                                                                           margin: const EdgeInsets.only( bottom: 12.0, left: 12.0, right: 12.0),
                                                                           borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                                                           message: 'Item already exists',
                                                                           duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
                                                                         ).show(context);
                                                                       } else if(value['error']){
                                                                         Flushbar(
                                                                           margin: const EdgeInsets.only( bottom: 12.0, left: 12.0, right: 12.0),
                                                                           borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                                                           message: 'Please try again later!!',
                                                                           duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
                                                                         ).show(context);
                                                                       }

                                                                       else{
                                                                         setState(() {

                                                                         });
                                                                         Flushbar(
                                                                           margin: const EdgeInsets.only( bottom: 12.0, left: 12.0, right: 12.0),
                                                                           borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                                                           message: 'Added to wishlist!',
                                                                           duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
                                                                         ).show(context);

                                                                       }

                                                                     });
                                                                   },
                                                                   child: Container(
                                                                     height: 35.0,
                                                                     width: 35.0,
                                                                     decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                                       borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14.0),
                                                                       color: AppColors.fontHeaderColor.withOpacity(0.2),
                                                                     ),
                                                                     child: const Center(
                                                                       child: Icon(Icons.favorite_outline_rounded, color: AppTaste.whiteThemeColor,),
                                                                     ),
                                                                   ),
                                                                 );
                                                               }

                                                             }else{
                                                               return Container(
                                                                 height: 35.0,
                                                                 width: 35.0,
                                                                 decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                                   borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(14.0),
                                                                   color: AppColors.fontHeaderColor.withOpacity(0.2),
                                                                 ),
                                                                 child: const Center(
                                                                   child: Icon(Icons.favorite_outline_rounded, color: AppTaste.whiteThemeColor,),
                                                                 ),
                                                               );
                                                             }

                                                           }
                                                       ),
                                                     ),
                                                   ],
                                                 ),
                                                 // const SizedBox(height: 8.0,),
                                                 // SizedBox(
                                                 //   width: 130.0,
                                                 //   child: SmallTextWidget(
                                                 //     align: TextAlign.start,
                                                 //     text: productCategorySnapshot.data[index]['company']['name'].toString(), color: AppTaste.font1ThemeColor, size: 12.0,),
                                                 // ),
                                                 const SizedBox(height: 8.0,),
                                                 Flexible(child: SizedBox(
                                                     width: 130.0,
                                                     child: SmallTextWidget(
                                                       align: TextAlign.start,
                                                       text: actualVisitedProductSnapshot.data['product']['title'].toString(), color: AppTaste.secondaryThemeColor, size: 14.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,))),
                                                 const SizedBox(height: 8.0,),
                                                 SizedBox(
                                                   width: 130.0,
                                                   child: SmallTextWidget(
                                                     align: TextAlign.start, text: 'KES${double.parse(actualVisitedProductSnapshot.data['selling_price'].toString()).toStringAsFixed(0)}'.replaceAllMapped(reg ,mathFunc), color: AppTaste.secondaryThemeColor, size: 14.0,),
                                                 ),
                                               ],
                                             ),
                                           );
                                         }else{
                                           return SizedBox();
                                         }
                                        }
                                      ),
                                    );
                                  }),
                                ),
                              );
                            }else{
                              return  HorizontalShimmerWidget(context);
                            }

                          }
                      ),
                    ),

 }
```

Comment: you need to assign the value from sharedPref searchHistory to the visitedProduct list and after add the current product id. now you are just taking an empty list add a single item in the list and saving it to SharedPref and every time it gets updated. you need to get the value first add new and assigned to pref.

Comment: Sorry the code has been updated, I added the wrong code

Answer (score 0):

I see your problem instantly because I had the same problem, The problem is that you are not adding to the `List<String> visitedProduct =  [];` so it is overriding each time, for example (my app):

```
List<String> joinedRides =  [];

_getDBRides() {
    return Expanded(
      child: FirebaseAnimatedList(
     
          Map Rides = snapshot.value as Map;
          Rides['key'] = snapshot.key; // this is important because you want to use this string (unique key of each item in the database to add to the list)

        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget listItem({
    required Map Rides,
  }) {
    saveprefs() async {
      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      await prefs.setStringList("joined_rides", joinedRides);
    }

    return Slidable(
            onPressed: (context) async {
              print(Rides['key']);
              if (!joinedRides.contains(Rides['key'])) {

// as you can see i add to the joinedRides list this is very important

                joinedRides.add(Rides['key']);
                saveprefs();
```

All that I am trying to show here is that you should add the code `Add recent viewed` to the `List<String> visitedProduct =  [];` list so that it can display a list

Comment: I understand you but am not using Map

Answer (score 0):

The deal is that method `setStringList(String key, List<String> value)` is **NOT** adding an item to your stored list but it's completely **replacing** your stored list with new `List<String> value`.

To achieve what you want you need to:

1. Get your stored list from shared preferences or if it was not stored previously create a new one:

   ```
   final savedInPrefsOrNewList = preferences.getStringList('your_key') ?? [];
   ```
2. Add your recently visited product id to the saved list:

   ```
   savedInPrefsOrNewList.add(widget.productId);
   ```
3. Save your list to the shared preferences:

   ```
   preferences.setStringList('your_key', savedInPrefsOrNewList);
   ```